# Update object in form view without any fields in Django

Tags: python, django

I want to create a `view` having a form, But the form should not show any fields.

In the `view` I has to be able to confirm/accept the object and thus change the status field of the object.

I guess I can make a simple view inheriting from FormView without creating any input fields, find the object in the dispatch method, and change the status field in the form_valid method.

But I wondered if it's better to use `UpdateView` since it has already implemented `get_object`, etc.

I have to use this approach many times, so I want to do it right the first time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need either of those. A simple DetailView would be easier; just override the `post` method and do the update there.